# obj.name() object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

```
    #polymorphism
class father:
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,age):
        self.name=firstname
        self.secoundname=lastname
        self.age=age
    def name(self):
        print("name"+self.name+"secoundname"+self.secoundname)
    def age(self):
        print("age"+str(self.age))
class son(father):
    def name(self):
        print("name"+self.name+"secoundname"+self.secoundname)
class daughter(father):
    def name(self):
        print("name"+self.name+"secoundname"+self.secoundname)
        
obj=father("k","a",23)
obj1=son("A","f",2)
obj2=daughter("f","y",6)
obj.name()
obj.age()
obj1.name()
obj1.age()
obj2.name()
obj2.age()
        
 

  

   

   > Blockquote


   **giving an error
```

> Blockquote
> obj.name()
> 'str' object is not callable
> what have been wrong in the above its just some silly mistake maybe it
> is a code with function class and objects does the object defined is
> incorrrect or what is the problem not able to make out can someone
> help me**

Comment: indentation is way off. Backspace your if elif elif and else so it is all on the same indentation level as your inputs.

Comment: Look at your indentation: neither `elif` matches the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn Indentation

```py
a = int (input("x"))
b = int (input ("y"))
c = int (input("z "))
if a ==b==c:
     print ("all equal")
elif(a>b and a>c):
    print("x is greatest")
elif(b>c and b>a):
    print("y is greatest ")
else :
    print("z is greatest")
```